# Cheese not detecting webcam

Tags: video, webcam

I'm trying to record video with a webcam I bought (Logitech C170), looks like Cheese doesn't detect it). It is wierd cause other apps like Camorama detect the webcam correctly. Camorama only takes pics but I need to record video. What could it be? Why does Cheese doesn't detect the camera. Should I give up Cheese and try with other video app?, which one would you recomend?

Comment: guvcview is good

Comment: Only for video? Or the camera is completely not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce the video resolution to 640x480 in Cheese preferences
2. Stop Cheese
3. Re-plug the camera
4. Start Cheese again.